# Is it correct to replace the second temperature by "that" or "it" ?What is this kind of grammar called?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality-in-context

I was reading some samrt apps on a web site.
On the web page, the author said this:

> This SmartApp enables you to automatically turn your fan on when SmartThings detects the thermostat is off, and 
>   **the temperature inside your home is hotter than the temperature
>   outside**

My teacher used to show us some sentences like this:

> I can swim better than you do
>   My dress is beautiful than yours

So, I am wondering if it is correct to use "that" or "it" to replace the second temperature in the sentence:

> The temperature inside your home is hotter than that outside
>   The temperature inside your home is hotter than it outside

What is this kind of grammar called?

Comment: The temperature in the train is higher than that outside

Comment: In a colloquial conversation that might become "... when it's hotter inside than outside".

Comment: "The temperature inside your home is hotter than it outside" should be "The temperature inside your home is hotter than it *is* outside"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"...the temperature inside your home is hotter than that outside" is correct. The word "that" is a demonstrative pronoun. The app's documentation seems to be choosing to be explicit rather than efficient in its description, a valid stylistic choice.

You could not use "it" here. The word "it" should not normally be used with modifiers. You can't say *"the red it", nor can you say *"it outside"

(note "my dress is *more* beautiful than yours")